# OpenSSL::HMACError: EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key: malloc failure in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I'm working on a rails app and I have this weird error that I don't know how to fix it. Some of my tests are failing when running `JWT.encode` and the error message is:

```
/Users/chille/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/openssl/hmac.rb:36:in `initialize': EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key: malloc failure (OpenSSL::HMACError)
```

I reinstalled ruby 3.1.1 and also reinstalled OpenSSL to use the opensssl@3 version since that one is compatible with ruby 3 but no success.

I would appreciate it if anyone have any clue on how to solve this.

- `MAC OS Monterrey 12.6.1`
- `Ruby 3.1.1`
- `Rails 7`

Comment: My issue was using an EC2 instance with ubuntu 22. Using an instance with Ubuntu 20 has OpenSSL 1.1 and not v3 which was causing the error. OpenSSL 1.1 should also be compatible with ruby 3 since its working for me now

Comment: This is still an issue with ruby 3.1.2p20 on Max OS Ventura 13.1

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a compatibility issue between OpenSSL 1.1 and now OpenSSL 3 (which Ruby 3 has moved to). Gems like `ruby-jwt` are sorting through those compatibility issues:
https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/issues/495

Supposedly, version [v2.5.0](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/releases/tag/v2.5.0) of JWT added support for OpenSSL >= 3.0, a clean install (or upgrade if you're not on that version) of JWT *should* solve the issue if they supported OpenSSL 3.0 correctly.

-- edit --

Update: Actually looks like they acknowledge that this was a bug in https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/issues/526 and it has since been fixed in Ruby's OpenSSL and JWT but only as of ~2 weeks ago, so no new version has been cut for it as of yet.

-- while we wait for the fix... --

In the meantime, if you don't directly need OpenSSL 3, you could rebuild your ruby using OpenSSL 1.1

Assuming you've install `openssl@1.1` via homebrew and are using [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby) to manage your Ruby versions (though this env option works for anything using ruby-build):

```bash
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)" asdf install ruby 3.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue. It's a compatibility issue between OpenSSL@1.1 and OpenSSL@3.0.7 on ruby version 3.1.0 and above. so I fixed by by following steps:

1. Uninstall **ruby 3.1.1**
2. Go to **.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/share/ruby-build/3.1.1**

Inside, this file you have installation package openssl@3.0.7 and ruby@3.1.1

```
install_package "openssl-3.0.7" "https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.0.7.tar.gz#83049d042a260e696f62406ac5c08bf706fd84383f945cf21bd61e9ed95c396e" openssl --if needs_openssl_102_300
install_package "ruby-3.1.1" "https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.1/ruby-3.1.1.tar.gz#fe6e4782de97443978ddba8ba4be38d222aa24dc3e3f02a6a8e7701c0eeb619d" ldflags_dirs enable_shared standard verify_openssl
```

Now, change 1st line with openssl@1.1 package:

```
install_package "openssl-1.1.1s" "https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1s.tar.gz#c5ac01e760ee6ff0dab61d6b2bbd30146724d063eb322180c6f18a6f74e4b6aa" openssl --if needs_openssl_101_111
```

After, changing line inside **.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/share/ruby-build/3.1.1** file. Install **ruby version 3.1.1** using following installation instructions from https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions. Use:

```
rbenv install 3.1.1 --verbose
```

You will see openssl@1.1 being installed and will resolve this issue.

For more, follow my medium post: [openssl-hmacerror-on-ruby](https://medium.com/@bajgain.sush7/openssl-hmacerror-on-ruby-8975c7cd6ec2)